# Snap an always-on-top form to the corner of the screen

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, docking, always-on-top

I have a tiny VB.net application that is a single `FixedToolWindow` form that I've made `TopMost = True` and partially transparent.  Is it possible to make this "dock" to the corner of the screen?  I like it sat in the bottom corner, but currently have to manually align it.

I'm using this on windows 7 machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *move* it in code to a corner. The following code will move it to the bottom right corner of the screen it is currently occupying:

```
Dim scr As Screen = Screen.FromControl(Me)
Me.Top = scr.WorkingArea.Top + scr.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height
Me.Left = scr.WorkingArea.Left + scr.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width
```

`WorkingArea` will place it above the taskbar, use `Bounds` instead if you want to place it over the taskbar (if it is visible)